# How does Spring MVC decide on conflict between homecontroller and jsp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mitreid-connect

I am converting a Spring MVC [app](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app) to Spring Boot.
The Spring app has a Home controller:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {...
    ...
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Principal p) {
    return "login";
    }
}
```

which should just display the word 'login'. This however seems to be ignored since it also has a login.jsp under src/webapp/WEB-INF/views which does a lot more, and this is what is displayed when it is run.

When I cut and paste simple-web-app into a Boot app I just get the word 'login'.

How does Spring magically ignore the word 'login' for the more complex jsp output? And how do I mimic this in Boot?

PS I have tried adding:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId> 
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@RestController` is not used for returning rendered `JSP`s. This is why Spring Boot just responds with the string `login`. Try to change this to the following:

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Principal p) {
        //do something with your Principal if you want...
        return "login";
    }
}
```

If you configured everything else right, Spring will look for a template called `login` (your `JSP`) and use this as the view.

`@RestController` is a Spring annotation used to build a [RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) (Rest-API endpoint defined in a controller).

By the way, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html) you can find some more info on how to proceed and also, unfortunately, some reasons not to use JSPs with Spring Boot and embedded containers but rather use a different templating engine.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Another answer to this question mentions view resolvers - this is indeed not unimportant! But it's kind of a special case with Spring Boot and JSPs. To get it right, [this article](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/) i just found may help!

Comment: Thanks! It now gives 404 on `/swa-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp'. Is there something else I need to do to point it there?

Comment: @schoon i edited my answer and added a link to an article that seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring framework, if you want to write a String to the response body then you'll use the keyword `@ResponseBody`. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc)

> @ResponseBody annotation and, therefore, writes directly to the response body versus view resolution and rendering with an HTML template.

Or, in your case, the [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotation that is

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.

If you don't use this keyword then Spring will search for a file with the given path. For this it uses a `viewResolver`. See [16.5 Views and resolving them](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html)

Here is an exemple where you can see the property that allow Spring to resolve the real path of your file :

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```